# Rails - Cocoon/simple form nested fields not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I'm trying to create nested fields in the edit/create section of a recipe book for ingredients, directions, and utensils, but only the outline of the fields show up, without any of the nested bits.

**Models**

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :ingredients
    has_many :directions
    has_many :utensils

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, reject_if: proc { |attributes| 
    attributes['name'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :directions, reject_if: proc { |attributes| 
    attributes['step'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :utensils, reject_if: proc { |attributes| 
    attributes['name'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end

class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :recipe
end

class Direction < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :recipe
end    

class Utensil < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :recipe
end
```

**Recipes Controller (params)**

```
def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :description, :image, 
    ingredients_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy], directions_attributes: 
    [:id, :step, :_destroy], utensils_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
end
```

**View**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3>Ingredients</h3>
      <div id="ingredients">
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient| %>
          <%= render "ingredients_fields", f: ingredient %>
          <div class="links">
            <%= link_to_add_association "Add Ingredient", f, :ingredients, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3>Directions</h3>
      <div id="directions">
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :directions do |direction| %>
          <%= render "directions_fields", f: direction %>
          <div class="links">
            <%= link_to_add_association "Add Step", f, :directions, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3>Utensils</h3>
      <div id="utensils">
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :utensils do |utensil| %>
          <%= render "utensils_fields", f: utensil %>
          <div class="links">
            <%= link_to_add_association "Add Utensil", f, :utensils, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
```

**Partial (for directions)**

```
<div class="form-inline.clearfix">
    <div class="nested-fields">
    <%= f.input :step, input_html: { class: "form-input form-control" } %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove", f, class: "form-button btn btn-default" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

The outline for utensils also isn't showing up and I'm not sure why.

Here's what it looks like: [nested forms not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAyqX.png)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: cocoon gem required proper html format to work, i think you're html is creating problem, try to comment row and col code and run in simple format

Comment: I commented the columns and rows out but it doesn't seem to make a difference, nothing shows in the boxes and the utensils box isn't there.

Comment: did you build your association in controller method like `@recipe.ingredients.build`?, i think this problem is related to your HTML structure, first try to implement this with simple UI, without using bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Are there any nested items?

Because if there are not it would explain the behaviour: your `link_to_add_association` is inside the `simple_fields_for` loop and so it will be shown for each nested item, but it will also never be shown if there are none (note: this could be desired behaviour, but I am guessing in most cases it is not).

All examples on the cocoon documentation place the `link_to_add_association` outside the `simple_fields_for` loop. If you have trouble reading haml, check the [ERB examples](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/ERB-examples).